# Google Bubble Chart custom tooltip column does not render

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip, google-visualization

I am trying to add a custom tooltip to a Bubble chart, to replace the default tooltip.  I have followed the instructions from the docs site ([here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content)) to add a new `string` column to the DataTable, with `role: 'tooltip'`.  However, you can see in the following JS fiddle example, that the custom tooltip content does not render.  The chart still shows the default tooltip.

Anyone know what I still need to do to get this custom tooltip content to show up?

http://jsfiddle.net/MPBmY/2/

Answer (score 2):

I ended up making a custom tool-tip pop-up that is working pretty well.

Assuming your div for the bubble chart is defined like this:

```
<div id="bubble_chart_div"></div>
```

Then I used the JavaScript below.  Please note that I left out that stuff about how to set up your google chart data and loading the google charts package.  This code just shows how to get your custom toolip popup.

```
    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;
    $(document).mousemove( function(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX; 
        mouseY = e.pageY;
    });

    /*
     *
     *instantiate and render the chart to the screen
     *
     */
    var bubble_chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('bubble_chart_div'));
    bubble_chart.draw(customer_product_grid_data_table, options);

    /*
     * These functions handle the custom tooltip display
     */
    function handler1(e){
        var x = mouseX;
        var y = mouseY - 130;
        var a = 1;
        var b = 2;
        $('#custom_tooltip').html('<div>Value of A is'+a+' and value of B is'+b+'</div>').css({'top':y,'left':x}).fadeIn('slow');
    }
    function handler2(e){
        $('#custom_tooltip').fadeOut('fast');
    }

    /*
     *  Attach the functions that handle the tool-tip pop-up
     *  handler1 is called when the mouse moves into the bubble, and handler 2 is called when mouse moves out of bubble
     */
    google.visualization.events.addListener(bubble_chart, 'onmouseover', handler1);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(bubble_chart, 'onmouseout', handler2);
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated at the bottom of the help document:

> At this time, HTML tooltips are supported for the following chart
>   types:
>
> - AreaChart
> - BarChart
> - CandlestickChart
> - ColumnChart
> - ComboChart
> - LineChart
> - ScatterChart

Unfortunately, Bubble Charts are not covered and therefore you cannot add the custom html tooltips to them. You can write a custom javascript to create tooltips if you'd like, but you cannot use the existing functionality to do what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, yes I ended up making my own tooltip and adding listeners to the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Mind sharing your code since this is an issue that comes up quite a bit?

Comment: Sure thing.  I will share an example.

Comment: I'd like custom tooltips in my bubble chart as well. The document quoted by jmac does not say only some charts support custom tooltips. It lists the chart types supporting *HTML* tooltips, which are a special, optional, feature described higher on the page.