# Fire dropdown from a data point within a Google Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have generated a Google Scatter Chart as follows:

```
<g>
<circle cx="393.66499999999996" cy="142.17399999999998" r="4.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f2f2f2"></circle>
<circle cx="362.655" cy="80.21199999999999" r="4.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f2f2f2"></circle>
<circle cx="211.29666666666665" cy="142.726" r="4.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f2f2f2"></circle>
<circle cx="427.62833333333333" cy="65.03199999999998" r="4.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f2f2f2"></circle>
<circle cx="423.93666666666667" cy="114.712" r="4.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f2f2f2"></circle>
<circle cx="169.95" cy="114.80399999999999" r="4.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f2f2f2"></circle>
<circle cx="418.03" cy="114.38999999999999" r="4.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f2f2f2"></circle>
<circle cx="356.74833333333333" cy="67.05599999999998" r="4.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f2f2f2"></circle>
</g>
```

I need to trigger a dropdown or popover when one of the circles is clicked and it needs to appear at the exact point the circle is in the SVG.

I know that I can listen for the select handler that Google makes available for it's charts ( https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events#Event_Listeners ) but I can't work out how to bind the JS to the click of the specific circle nor get the dropdown / popover to appear right at that point.

Comment: You can try to implement a custom tooltip the way done in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566766/google-bubble-chart-custom-tooltip-column-does-not-render). This is beyond my level of understanding, so I suggest you give it a read and see if it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I got this to work by hacking together a absolute position for a drop down box and then trigger it on the select event of any point in the Google Chart.

Not great, but it'll do for now.